# Unsupported Operand Type when using global variables in Flask Python

Tags: python, variables, flask, global

I'm trying to create a simple page using flask and python that shows how many times a page has been viewed.

I'm trying to do this by creating a global variable and then += 1 to it every time the page refreshes.

Im running into two problems

the first one being that the page doesn't show the global variable at all

[Variable not being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beQro.png)

The second being that when I try to modify the global variable I get a type error which is confusing me.

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'function' and 'int'

[Python Code I am trying to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/048Xe.png)

[TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBshu.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm still very new to both Python and flask

Comment: The name of your function is views().  When you write views += 1, Python thinks you're trying to increment the function, not the variable.  Rename one or the other of them.

Comment: Please read [why you should not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

You have two different things called `views`, your function and your variable.  Both are global, so `views` refers to whichever of them was defined last.  In this case, that is the function.  Calling `views += 1` tells Python to try and increment the function.

Rename one of them.